# expected unqualified-id before 'public'

Tags: c++

I've searched everywhere and cant find an answer for this error
"expected unqualified-id before 'public'"
this is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static int playerHP;
static int playerPWR;

public:
{
static int playerHP = 100;
static int playerPWR = 4;
}

int main(){

}
```

p.s. This is in my main.

Comment: `public:` not inside class?

Comment: Whatever book taught you that: burn it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you wrote this ridiculous code, but I assume you may want this:

```
class Player
{
public:
    static int playerHP;
    static int playerPWR;
};

int Player::playerHP = 100;
int Player::playerPWR = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to build a class or struct. This `public` statement would work inside either of those, but not alone.

Try reading [this class introduction](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) and see if that makes it clearer.

If you don't want a class, because you're not trying to build a group of similar objects, then you can place these variables inside your `main()` - in that case, you might want to read about [variable scope](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm).